# What was it in cat food that the aliens from District Nine loved so much?

Tags: district-9

In *District 9* the aliens (commonly and derogatorily called 'Prawns') find cat food addictive, as per the [Alien Catnip trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienCatnip) (warning TV Tropes link!)

Was it ever revealed in or out of universe what about it was so addicting?

Comment: A common fan theory is taurine, which has high levels in cat food (added in part because cats need it, but many foods that humans might make for their pet cats, like chicken, lack it. Also, it's apparently cheap to synthesize).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that rings a bell for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

According to interviews with Neill Blomkamp, the choice of cat food was in part because [cat food is used for prawn fishing on Earth](http://www.fishinbc.com/prawn-bait/). Based on the details of prawn bait, specifically that oil, either from the bait itself, or added later from fish, is used to lure prawns to the bait, and that oil is similarly attractive in human diets as a high-energy substance with substantial volatiles that allow it to be easily detected and found, it is likely the fish oil in the cat food that the prawns crave.

Comment: I've seen this referenced repeatedly, but ***which*** interviews with Neill Blomkamp are you citing? The language is similiar enough in every reference that they all appear to be copy/pasting directly from the movie trivia section on IMDB, but no source is ever given. Could this be a case of citogenesis?

Comment: I think that's entirely possible. I've only found two interviews with him about *District 9* and neither mention the cat food.

Comment: Also possibly working against my answer, I've seen references to "prawns" actually referring to African crickets who resemble the sealife. Admittedly, they too eat cat food.

Comment: I've found an interview where Blomkamp and the stars talk about eating catfood, but there's nothing in it about why they picked it.

Comment: As per my original objection, have you been able to find which interviews in which he said this, or is this just internet hearsay?

Comment: @Valorum Truthfully, I've given little thought to this answer In the time since I provided it. But, I suspect you may be right that this is hearsay that just keeps getting passed on, at least until we can get Neil to weigh in on it.

Comment: That being the case, can you at least point to where you read this in the first place? That might be useful in tracking down the original source

Comment: I'll see what I can dig up.